# Common formatoptions for many tables

Tags: jqgrid

I have many jqGrid tables where is repeated this code:

```
colModel: [{
    ...
    formatter:'actions',
    formatoptions:{
        keys:true,
        delOptions: {
            url: "url",
            caption: "caption",
            top:167,
            left:142,
            width: 400,
            modal:true,
            resize: false,
            delicon: [true,'left','ui-icon-trash'],
            beforeShowForm: function(formid) {}
        }
    }
},
...
]
```

Changing only the url and caption.

How to make, what to avoid duplication of this code everytime ?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: Oleg, I use jQuery Grid Plugin 4.4.3 – last version which support IE6 (http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)

Comment: **Why you use the retro version** of jqGrid 4.4.3 published almost 4 years ago? It was the time of Chrome 24, Firefox 18, IE10. Do you believe, that the retro version still works good with the current web browsers Chrome 54, Firefox 50, Microsoft Edge 38 and IE11? You should take in considerations the version of jQuery and jQuery UI too. The options of jqGrid heavy depend on the fork and the version of jqGrid. The possibilities of 4.4.3 are very restricted. If you want to hold your code smaller and more maintainable you should start with upgrading of jqGrid.

Comment: Okay, which stable version do you recommend for the solution of my question?

Comment: [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.5 is the fork, which I develop and which I would recommend you. I recommend you to read [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) and to use additionally *column templates*. You can specify common options via `$.jgrid.del`, `$.jgrid.defaults` and so on additionally.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: You have there ([link](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods)) a small misprint. Is duplicated closeAfterEdit: true, instead of the closeAfterAdd: true

Comment: Using your article has reduced my code by 30%

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the type. By the way the wiki is opened for everybody for writing. You can make any modifications yourself or to write one more wiki article.